# Can VB.NET be used as a game engine?

Tags: vb.net

I know VB.NET, and I've been planning on creating a simple 2d game engine. I got no problems with creating such engine and running the actual game. However, I've been told that VB.NET might not be the best choice for "working too much with graphics". I'd like to know if that's true. Can VB.NET truly not manage efficiently loads of graphics simultaneously on the screen? If no, what kind of software am I supposed to use for creating this engine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found that people generally view VB.NET as a subpar language, and mostly associate it with Visual Basic 6.0 (or earlier).

In the .NET world, VB.NET is a first class citizen that simply has a verbose syntax. It's particularly because of the verbosity that I would probably choose C#, if not going with C++.

Still, you can use VB.NET to work with whatever drawing libraries that you want, and you can even use it with XNA and Managed DirectX. It can even be linked against unmanaged libraries as long as you are willing to do to the required interop.

As for managing the graphics on the screen efficiently, it really depends on how well you do it, and how much you want done. If someone can do it well in C#, then you can do it well in VB.NET with the exception of [unsafe code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx). It's too general to say either way given the vague "simple 2D game engine" description, but chances are it is more than possible.

These days, managed code is quickly catching up to unmanaged code, and while it's not quite perfect, it is really impressively good.

Comment: Very glad you added that it can't have the `unsafe` keyword. VB.NET is still missing a couple of things that both C# and C++/CLR can provide.

Comment: @rudi_visser: And C# is missing some things from vb.net (e.g. exception filters).

Comment: Indeed! But talking in context of writing a game engine, there may be an advantage to using C# or C++/CLR.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the language you need to consider as much as the Framework.

Suggest you look at [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791):

- [Your First Game - XNA Game Studio in 2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx) (step-by-step tutorial)

Also, DirectX:

- [DirectX Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/directx/default.aspx)
- [Learn DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/bb896684)

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET Already supports XNA including on Windows Phone 7. So if you are looking to develop games and if you language of choice is VB + XNA you are all set to go.

Take a look at the official announcement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2011/03/28/xna-is-coming-to-visual-basic.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic's primary use is for Win 32 Apps with a standard GUI. If you are planning on building a game I definitely recommend C++. It has faster execution speed and better libraries for game development. Visual Basic will not deliver as good of performance of C++ would give you. IMO It would be better for you and the user.

Comment: That's not 100% correct. vb.net is not VB6. Both vb.net and C# can produce fast code

Comment: : C++ being faster than C# is a Myth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much of the graphics issues in vb but as far as i have heard you can't create games for xbox using vb.net, it only supports PC.
XNA game studio can be used for game development. Although it is supposed for c#, you can find how to use it with vb in here...

http://www.alanphipps.com/VisualBasicdotNET-XNA.html

Comment: See _very_ [recent changes from the VB team here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/05/25/vb-support-for-the-xna-platform.aspx). _"XNA now fully supports Visual Basic on all platforms (Xbox360/Windows and Windows Phone 7)."_

Answer (score 1):

If you are still relatively new to programming then C++ is more than likely to make you quit early.

Don't aim at C++ until you have at learned C#.

C++ is a great and diverse language but definitely not friendly grounds for anyone who hasn't been programming for a long time. This is ESPECIALLY considering if your first language is one such a VB.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer the Topic?
Yes vb.net can make a game, arcade,FPS,RPG,MMO or what ever you what within your ability to code. if you wanna learn some find playing with open source engines to get the feel helps. so try looking up some and give that a go.

---

my comment is at the person above's comment,
Visual Basic can do alot, and we find out new stuff all the time.
i seen vb6 game engines work  well, graphical and feature wise.

wile visual basic is more down to earth for writing, C++ isnt ik its not, ive tried it.
but VB i can pick up easyr.

my experience ?? 2007 to present day, ive work with vb6 mmo game engine source codes,
Mirage,Elysium,Eclipse,EA,EFF
ive also tried using irrlect engine years back.

for a beginner  should learn VB.net or C# .
C++ is to complex.

---